# Alfresco custom UI controls - Associations

Tags: javascript, controls, alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm trying to build a custom UI control in alfresco to display the associations of an object type that I have.

Basically I have two object types; Code, which is a key value pair, and CodeScheme which contains multiple child associations to codes, it's essentially a mirror of a map structure I have in a different system.

The problem I have is that the codes are automatically generated, so they get the UID names, whereas really I'd like to present them as 'key=value', 'key=value', etc (ideally I'd like to present it as a table).

I've already created a custom control and added it to share-config-custom, and confirmed that the configuration is working correctly. What I'm not really clear on now is:

a) How to attach a javascript to the control so that I can process the association data.
b) How to get hold of the codes in javascript, and read their properties.

I'm just looking for a push in the right direction.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to use a [form filter](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/dev-extensions-share-form-filters.html). Your form filter could iterate over the child references, fetch each child node, grab the data you want to display and then add one or more new properties with that data.

Then, your form control is hooked to the fields your form filter dynamically added to the form data. It can then read and display the data as needed.

Without a form filter I think you'd have to use JavaScript to parse the child association refs and use AJAX calls to fetch each child's node data, then format that as needed. The form filter idea would be less traffic from the browser.